# Constructor vs static instance

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to php and had to work with an existing code base. In this library there is a class which deals with the mysql database. However, they start to instantiate an object with a static getInstance function:

```
public static function get_instance() {
  if(null == self::$instance) {
    $c = __CLASS__;
    self::$instance = new $c();
  }
  return self::$instance;
}
```

I don't see the advantage of this static function in comparison to an usual constructor. How do I have to deal with my login credentials? Do I have to make them static, too?

Comment: It's using the [singleton design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) - http://coderoncode.com/2014/01/27/design-patterns-php-singletons.html

Comment: Is it reasonable to use singletons with a database class?

Comment: It's commonplace to use singletons with a database class; but many developers dislike the use of singletons in general, and it does restrict you to a single database connection so you can't access multiple databases.... search the web and you'll find a lot of objections to the use of singletons (http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SingletonsAreEvil) but understanding why they are considered bad, and knowing when it is appropriate to use them is probably more important than simply condemning their use

Comment: Very helpful, thank you. But I have one more question ;) Is it possible to change the scheme after instantiate with another scheme or do I have to go away from singleton with the need of multiple schemes? (FYI: I don't need these schemes at the same time)

Comment: That depends on the other methods available in the class for setting database/user/password etc. As they're not being passed in through the constructor, I'd guess that such methods are available

Comment: @BeJay the idea of the Singleton is to keep a single instance of something in order to prevent other people or you yourself as a programmer to make multiple instances of something, that basically wraps it up. What Mark told you is completely valid and I would like to add that it is never recommended to use static instances because they represent global state which makes them hard to test because they are accessible between different classes. With singletons like this it would be hard to change the scheme without doing some singleton hacks to replace the instance. Try to remove the statics.

Comment: I have to disagree. Singleton is really common in database connections. You can still connect to other schema using a diferent Singleton to that other database. What you are doing here is making sure that there will be only one connection at that database at a time.

Comment: @CarlosGoce - surely by definition having more than one singleton isn't using a singleton, it's using a [multiton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiton_pattern)